# how to store a collection of primitive type (String) into database

Tags: android, android-sqlite, ormlite, primitive-types, foreign-collection

I'm trying to map my classes to the SQLite database using ORMLite and i have trouble to store a collection of String i have this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No fields have a DatabaseField annotation in
     class java.lang.String
```

this error is self explanatory but how i do to store a collection of strings should i extend String class and add the annotations needed in order to do that ?
in the annotation of the field i added datatype.serializable but that too wouldn't work.
here's my class where i have the problem :

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "parameters")

public class Parameters {

    // id is generated by the database and set on the object automagically
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    int id_parameters;

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = true)
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Integer id;

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false)
    @JsonProperty("account_id")
    private Integer account_id;

    @ForeignCollectionField
    @JsonProperty("languages")
    private Collection<String> languages;
    ...
}
```

the field in question is languages!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, you can't just do a collection of strings.  You will need to create a wrapper class with a `String` field in it as well as a foreign `Parameters` field:

```
public class Language {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    int id;
    @DatabaseField
    String language;
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
    Parameters parameters;
}
```

Here's the [description of foreign collections](http://ormlite.com/docs/foreign-collections) from the FM.  To quote:

> Remember that when you have a ForeignCollection field, the class in the collection must (in this example Order) must have a foreign field for the class that has the collection (in this example Account). If Account has a foreign collection of Orders, then Order must have an Account foreign field. It is required so ORMLite can find the orders that match a particular account.